# PyCharm - how to use a folder that is not in the base directory

Tags: python, django, directory, pycharm

I want to use a folder that is not in the base directory of my django project without adding it in to the base directory.

Comment: Do you want to import files from that directory into your Python code? Or do you just want to access the folder from Pycharm?

Comment: How do you expect to use this folder once you deploy your project? What is it you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **File > settings** menu and then goto **project: foo > Project Structure** and press **Add Content Root**, then select destination directory.
and after folder added in list, right click on the folder and set as source, in last step press **OK**...